# Socket.on() does not execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make a chat app with socket.io and I've run into a weird occurrence: my server receives the messages that I sent but the client doesn't.

**Server Code:**

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\index.html');
  });

  io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit(msg)
      console.log('message: ' + msg)
    })
  })

http.listen(3002,function(){
    console.log('listening on 3002');
});
```

**And here is the client's code:**

```
<script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          console.log(msg)
     // $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    });

</script>
```

where #m is am input field with the message I want to send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to emit an event name with some data :

From [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventName-%E2%80%A6args-ack) :

> socket.emit(eventName[, …args][, ack])

on the Server :

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      io.emit('newMessage', msg )  
//             ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^
//             event name   data

      console.log('message: ' + msg)
    })
  })
```

on the client :

```
socket.on('newMessage', function(msg){
      console.log(msg)
});
```